# Desktop menu, .desktop files and xdg-desktop-menu

Tags: linux, rpm

What's the relationship between .desktop files in the /usr/share/applications, the xdg-desktop-menu command and update-desktop-database command?

I'm trying to make a RPM that creates a desktop icon for my app. In the RPM, I install the vendor-appname.desktop file into /usr/share/applications. Then I have the following post-install script:

```
if [ -x "`which xdg-desktop-menu 2>/dev/null`" ]; then
    xdg-desktop-menu install $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/share/applications/vendor-myapp.desktop
fi

if [ -x "`which update-desktop-database 2>/dev/null`" ]; then
    update-desktop-database &> /dev/null || :
fi
```

And the icon is not created. The icon IS created if I run the

```
xdg-desktop-menu install $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/share/applications/vendor-myapp.desktop
```

command manually later on, as a non-root. If I do so as a root (which is, supposedly, how the RPM does it), the icon is not created. Also, I have a very strong suspicion that the `update-desktop-database` under if[] bit is not executed. It is executed  when I manually run the whole `if[]` statement.

Fedora Linux with Gnome.

Answer (score 2):

On Fedora, be sure of:

```
BuildRequires: desktop-file-utils
Requires(post): desktop-file-utils
Requires(postun): desktop-file-utils
```

Then (%{SOURCE1} is your desktop file):

```
%install
[...]
desktop-file-install                                    \
--dir=${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_datadir}/applications         \
%{SOURCE1}
[...]

%post
update-desktop-database &> /dev/null || :

%postun
update-desktop-database &> /dev/null || :
```

If you install your own icon, you also need to update the icon cache, adding in the relative specfile sections:

```
%post
touch --no-create %{_datadir}/icons/hicolor &>/dev/null || :

%postun
if [ $1 -eq 0 ] ; then
    touch --no-create %{_datadir}/icons/hicolor &>/dev/null
    gtk-update-icon-cache %{_datadir}/icons/hicolor &>/dev/null || :
fi

%posttrans
gtk-update-icon-cache %{_datadir}/icons/hicolor &>/dev/null || :
```

Refs:

- http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/PackagingGuidelines#Desktop_files
- http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/desktop-file-utils
- http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging/ScriptletSnippets#Icon_Cache